# Java Concurrent List

Tags: java, list, dictionary, collections, concurrency

I am currently creating a software with different threads. This software accepts add-ons. Since all threads are accessible by the add-ons, things like lists, maps, etc. can be edited and iterated by add-ons.

I am trying to figure out the best way of making these lists concurrent so that the add-on code will be mostly free of locks and synchronized blocks.

But also i am trying not to lose as much performance (like I would if I would use a `CopyOnWrite` solution).

My current idea is to create own lists, maps, etc. backed by their non-concurrent type and nesting the methods like (add, get, etc.) in synchronized blocks.

Since this is a lot of work I just wanted to know if there is someone who maybe knows a much better solution to my problem.

**Edit 1:**

I was asked to provide more information about my project. As mentioned above I have multiple threads concurrently running all of those threads have their own main loop for executing different tasks.

The whole idea behind having multiple threads in my application is to relief the main thread of the application. All of those threads are alive as long as the application itself is.

For Example: The application's rendering is processed in ThreadA. The basic data processing of the application happens in ThreadB. All the add-ons are loaded and "started" by ThreadC.

Add-Ons can modify stuff in ThreadA and ThreadB.

Currently the easiest solution for me (and most annoying for add-on developers) is to leave it like this and force the add-on developers to use locks or synchronized-blocks. Which in my opinion will sooner or later lead to exceptions and dead-locks (not to mention that the code of add-ons  would become very messy)

Comment: Anything [here](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/util/concurrent/package-summary.html) to tickle your fancy?

Comment: There is no way to suggest an implementation with barely any information about your software's architecture.  My first thought after reading this is "premature optimization".  How do you know the JDK concurrent list implementation (which you referenced) is not going to perform well?  A think a better question would be suited around a prototype using the java.list.concurrent implementation with a profile dump to see if there are optimizations as opposed to literally implementing your own concurrent list which is a project in itserlf

Comment: I realize my suggestion is no small task - so feel free to expand upon your original post with additional architectural information and I'll do my best to answer, albeit my answer is likely not going to suggest implementing your own concurrent list with better performance but I could look at your architecture and possibly give a suggestion based off my experience

Comment: @ChrisMaggiulli thank you for your comment. I added more information.

Comment: The idea of wrapping all methods in a synchronized blocks is not new `Collections.synchronizedXXX` already exist for this purpose. But they are fundamentally flawed - if you need to carry out a compound operation, for example "add if size > x`, you need to synchronise anyway. I would suggest in the strongest possible terms against your idea - frankly, rolling your own concurrency when your first idea is to wrap everything in synchronized blocks is highly inadvisable! I would suggest doing much, much more reading before tackling such a project.

Comment: Do you have a theoretically min/max/average number of threads?  Do you have any estimate around the min/max/average size of your lists?  Are the lists heavily organized around things that will be ordered/somewhat order/completely unordered?  Is this a distributed system?  Are you running in a servlet or OSGi container?

Comment: Reading your application description you have added, I suggest using an Actor Model - where add-ons run on a single thread and send messages to your application internals. These internals also run on a single thread and process messages. This way you remove all your threading concerns...

Comment: To be completely upfront from what I've heard thus far I'm likely just going to reiterate my initial point or possibly parrot what Boris has said.  There is a difference between building to scale and premature optimization.  Shipping your project with it's own concurrency framework is definitely in the later category and is likely going to cost more than it's value.  I still can't really suggest anything because your edit clarified your use case a bit but didn't really address the systems architecture.

Comment: @ChrisMaggiulli The amount of Threads is fixed to 7. The amount of lists can vary. And are completely unordered. The software itself is a server that provides a TCP endpoint for clients, that use the server to process the data.

Comment: Why are you building the server and not using an OSGi container?  Thus far OSGi modules seem like they fit your use case perfectly (although dont really address your concurrency concerns which likely won't exist is you rethink the problem)

Comment: @MysteriousPerson it doesn't sound to me like *any* of your plans will allow add-ons written by different developers to work together across threads safely.  Just replacing all your data structures with thread-safe equivalents doesn't usually do the job!